# AS3 Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, class

I've been searching for this type of error on every sites but haven't found any solution to this. The error is in `Gold` class at `_money.addText(stage);` The thing that makes me more confused is that when `_money.addText(stage);` is called in the `Main` class it works without any error. Please help. Thanks!

And the other thing that I want to ask too. In `Gold` class. I tried tracing to see how the count for the money does. And it stays at 5 no matter how many golds I've clicked. I wonder why it won't increase ?

Here is the Gold class:

```
package
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Gold extends MovieClip
    {
        private var _main:Main
         private var gold:Gold;
        public var destinationY:int;

        private var _money:Money =  new Money();


        public function Gold(main:Main):void 
        {

                          _main=main;
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goldClicked);

        }

        private function goldClicked(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,goldClicked);
                 _main.goldContainer.removeChild(e.currentTarget as Gold);
            _money.money+=5;
            trace(_money.money);
            _money.addText(stage);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the Money class :

```
package
{   

    import flash.text.TextField

    public class Money
    {
        public var money:int;
        private var moneyText:TextField =  new TextField();

        public function Money():void
        {

        }

        public function addText(stage:Object):void
        {
            stage.addChild(moneyText);
            moneyText.x = 5;
            moneyText.y = 5;
            moneyText.height = 20;
            moneyText.textColor=0x000000;
            updateMoney();
        }
         public function updateMoney():void {
            moneyText.text="Money: "
        }
    }
}
```

Some parts of Main class :

```
package
{   

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;


    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        private var field:Array;
        public var gold:Gold;
        public var goldContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
        private var goldTimer:Timer = new Timer(2000);
        public var _money:Money = new Money();

        public function Main():void
        {
            setupField();
            _money.addText(stage);
            goldSet();
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrm);
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a display object you do not have access to stage until it has been added to stage. So you will need to wait for that event.

Change

```
    public function Main():void
    {
        setupField();
        _money.addText(stage);
        goldSet();
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrm);
    }
```

To

```
    public function Main():void
    {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage)
    }

    public function onStage(e:event):void{
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage)
        setupField();
        _money.addText(stage);
        goldSet();
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrm);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for answering, but it still doesn't work. the exactly same error still occurs.

Comment: In your click handler has that object been added to stage? in that handler you are accessing stage

Comment: Try changing this _money.addText(stage) to _money.addText(_main)